# Flutter, how to display data from a BIG5 json?

Tags: flutter, decode

I would like to display some BIG5 characters from a jSON (which is created from Capesoft NetTalk service with SoftVelocity Clarion web server), but how do I display the characters properly?

```
List<dataRecord> parseJson(String responseBody) {
    final parsed =
        convert.jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<dataRecord>((json) => dataRecord.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Future<List<dataRecord>> fetchData(http.Client client) async {
    isLoading = true;
    print(widget.clientID.toString());
    final response = await client.get(
      Uri.parse('some_api'),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      },
    );
    return parseJson(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: Try using character encoder packages like enough_convert: ^1.6.0 https://pub.dev/packages/enough_convert

Comment: Thanks Risheek, I tried install the package, but the example only shows encode/decode the same string using only 1 coding.  Can you teach me how to change the coding from 1 to another?